# Complex WebGrid Binding in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Let's say I have a Parent object like this (in pseudo code)

```
public Parent()
  string FirstName
  string LastName
  IEnumarable<Child> Children
  Child GetOldestChild()  <- A function that returns the oldest child in Children

public Child()
  string ChildFirstName
  string ChildLastName
  int ChildAge
```

Ok, so I want to bind a WebGrid an IEnumarable< Parent >, and in each row I want to display the first and last name of the parent, and the firstname/lastname/age of the oldest child.

Getting the parent columns is easy, I can just bind like this:

```
grid.Column("FirstName")
```

But getting the oldest child data is what I don't know how to do. This doesn't work, but it's what I want to accomplish:

```
grid.Column("GetOldestChild().ChildFirstName")
```

Hopefully I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
public Parent()
  string FirstName
  string LastName
  IEnumarable<Child> Children
  private Child GetOldestChild()
  public Child OldestChild { get { return GetOldestChild() } };

public Child()
  string ChildFirstName
  string ChildLastName
  int ChildAge

grid.Column("OldestChild.ChildFirstName")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I came up with that will allow you to accomplish what you need without creating extraneous properties on your model and will also allow you get parametized data:

[Binding MVC WebGrid column to source's dictionary property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580503/binding-mvc-webgrid-column-to-sources-dictionary-property-value/21582109#21582109)