# Bind Datatable to webgrid in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

MVC3 Hi  I have to bind the Datatable to webgrid in mvc3 also i have to apply paging for the same.
but i am confused should i have to create a model for this or simply i can bind the datatable which contains complex column data to webgrid.

I have same datatable in asp where i simply bind it to grid datasource property.
But i m not finding any ways to accomplish it in mvc3

I have to create follwing grid structure.

```
          Reservation                               
Day Date              Time  CustomerName    Party Size      Type    
TUE 13/01/2011        7.00  Sachin Marne    10               P1
                      08.30 Sagar Wagh      20               P2
TUE 14/01/2011        7.00  Sachin Marne    10               P1
                      08.30 Sachin Marne    20               P2
                      08.00 Sachin Marne    10               P1
                      08.30 Sachin Marne    20               P2
```

Please any one has any idea, Please suggest.
Thanks,
Sachin.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you creating a view model:

```
public class ReservationViewModel
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int PartySize { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action query your repository to fetch the datatable and then map it to a `IEnumerable<ReservationViewModel>` which is what you would pass to the view. Inside the view you could build your WebGrid from the view model as [some examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) are illustrating.

Comment: Hi Darin Dimitrov
Thanks For Replay.                                                    But my question is i have many fileds for Day and Date.Means My day and Date may be one but for single day i have no of records for Time,Customer Name,Party Size,type which will be datatable will webgrid support this type of complex binding.

Answer (score 0):

@Sachin - You should create view model for binding the webgrid as Darin suggested. for complex data type, follow the [Complex type in WebGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273138/complex-type-in-webgrid) link  i think this would resolve your issue.