# Binding MVC WebGrid column to source's dictionary property value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I'm using MVC's WebGrid throughout my application and it's been working great.  I'm setting the columns for the grid in my controller code and then passing that to my view.  I add a new column like this where `columns` is a `List<MvcWebGridColumn>`:

```
columns.Add(new WebGridColumn { ColumnName = "Path", Header = "Full Path", Filter = ... });
```

And then in my view, I set the grid columns from my view model like this:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    footerStyle: "hide",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    htmlAttributes: new { id = @Model.Id },
    columns: @Model.Columns)
```

Up until this point, setting the columns in the code has worked great as the columns have been known, first-level properties of my models.  Now things are more complicated and I don't know how to handle it with the WebGrid.  Here is an example model:

```
public class Requirement
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to set a WebGrid's column in the code using the value from the `Field` dictionary property's key.  I'm trying this, but it's not working:

```
columns.Add(new WebGridColumn { ColumnName = String.Format("Fields[\"{0}\"]", key), Header = label });
```

I tried also putting a method `GetFieldValue(string key)` method on my `Requirement` model, but it doesn't like that either.  It seems like it can only handle exactly matching an object's property identifier.

I'm not sure if this is possible using WebGrid out of the box or if I have to extend the functionality.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317207/mvc-webgrid-dynamic-columns

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that person knows the sub property identifiers.  I'm trying to get a value for a column from a Dictionary property by key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I just came up with a way to handle this that doesn't seem too hacky.

To restate the problem, I believe the MVC WebGrid uses reflection to set the `ColumnName` property so the string you enter for that needs to be directly accessible via the object's API eg. `"Id"`, `"Field.Address.Name"`, etc.  The problem in my case is that the value I need for my column's row comes from a Dictionary and it doesn't seem like you can pass a parameter (key, index, etc) into the `ColumnName` to get the value I need.

My solution is to avoid using the `ColumnName` property of the WebGrid entirely when resolving the value to be displayed.  I simply enter a value for the grid's model that I know exists for the `ColumnName`, in my case "Id".  This is just used so the WebGrid will render.  Then, since the `Format` of the WebGridColumn uses a dynamic function, I can define my column value using whatever I want:

```
columns.Add(new WebGridColumn
{
    ColumnName = "Id",
    Header = field.Label,
    Format = x => new HtmlString(x.Value.GetEntityFieldValue(field.Field))
});
```

I soon realized that this will mess up sorting.  MVC WebGrid's black-box sort simply uses the ColumnName in the sort query so every column for me now has "?sort=Id".  If you're not sorting, then you're OK.  If you are, you'll have to implement a custom sorting solution like I'm currently doing.